# How to prove $2x+1$ is the unit of $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$?

Tags: group-theory

Same as what I stated in the title.
What are the general steps to find or prove a polynomial is the unit of a ring of polynomials.

Def for the ring of polynomials $R[x] = \{ a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_n x^n | a_0,..,a_n \in R,  n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\}$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a _unit_ in a ring? That should give you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If an element $a$ of a ring is [nilpotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent) $a^n=0$, then $1+a$ is always invertible. Such elements $1+a$ with $a$ nilpotent are called [unipotents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unipotent). Observe that

$$(1+a)(1-a+a^2-a^3+a^4-\dots)=1$$

Now, the second factor on the left is actually a finite sum, since $a^n=0$ and so $a^{n+1}=a^{n+2}=\dots=0$.

In your ring, $2x$ is nilpotent since $2$ already is: $2^3=8=0$ in $\mathbb Z_8$, and so $(2x)^3=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In a ring $R$, an element $u \in R$ is a *unit* if there exists a $v \in R$ such that $uv=1$ where $1$ is the multiplicative identity in $R$.

You're working in $R=\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$. So what you're looking for is a polynomial $u(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_8[x]$ such that $(2x+1)u(x)=1$.